# Ruby Loops need some explaining

Tags: ruby, loops

I have this problem and have been having issues with loops and how the pertain to this statement. If someone could walk me through it.

```
ruby
beatles = [
  {
    name: nil,
    nickname: "The Smart One"
  },
  {
    name: nil,
    nickname: "The Funny One"
  },
  {
    name: nil,
    nickname: "The Cute One"
  },
  {
    name: nil,
    nickname: "The Quiet One"
  }
]

i = 0
while i < beatles.length
  # Your code here!
  i += 1
end

i = 0
while i < beatles.length
  puts "Hi, I'm #{beatles[i][:name]}.  I'm #{beatles[i][:nickname]}!"
  i += 1
end
```

Comment: So what is your question?

Comment: Maybe you have to replace the `nil`s with name-strings in the hashes.

Comment: If you want to fill in the names: `> beatles.zip(["John", "Ringo", "Paul", "George"]).map {|h, n| h[:name]=n; h}`

Answer (score 1):

```
beatles.class         #=> Array
beatles.length        #=> 4
beatles[0]            #=> {:name=>nil, :nickname=>"The Smart One"}
beatles[1]            #=> {:name=>nil, :nickname=>"The Funny One"}
beatles[2]            #=> {:name=>nil, :nickname=>"The Cute One"}
beatles[3]            #=> {:name=>nil, :nickname=>"The Quiet One"}
beatles[4]            #=> nil

h = beatles[2]        #=> {:name=>nil, :nickname=>"The Cute One"}
h.class               #=> Hash
h[:name]              #=> nil 
h[:nickname]          #=> "The Cute One"
beatles[2][:name]     #=> nil
beatles[2][:nickname] #=> "The Cute One"

i = 0    
while i < beatles.length
  puts "i=#{i}"
  puts "Hi, I'm #{beatles[i][:name]}.  I'm #{beatles[i][:nickname]}!"
  i += 1
end

i=0
Hi, I'm .  I'm The Smart One!
i=1
Hi, I'm .  I'm The Funny One!
i=2
Hi, I'm .  I'm The Cute One!
i=3
Hi, I'm .  I'm The Quiet One!
```